# How to add custom javascript into <head> from custom plugin

Tags: javascript

I wrote a plugin but it keeps adding custom javascript into  section not into  section of every page.
Can anyone help me or give me a hint how to add js into  section?

```
public constructor {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'custom_js_register' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this,  'custom_js_print' ) );
}

function custom_js_register() {
    wp_register_script('custom_button', 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx/js/Button.js');
}

function custom_js_print() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_button');
}
```

also instead of just loading js, I want to be able to do something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx/js/Button.js" charset="UTF-8">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the hook to enqueue the scripts in WordPress.
Use the hook `wp_enqueue_scripts`for the front end and `admin_enqueue_scripts` for the back end side.

If you are enqueueing scripts and styles, you will want to use one of these three hooks:

1. `wp_enqueue_scripts` (for the frontend)
2. `login_enqueue_scripts` (for the
   login screen)
3. `admin_enqueue_scripts` (for the admin dashboard)

It is enough to use one method for register and enqueue of scripts. The difference is the benefit for other developers to de-register the script.

```
public constructor() {

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this,  'custom_js_register' ) );
}

public function custom_js_register() {

    wp_register_script( 'custom_button', 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx/js/Button.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_button' );

}
```

Als the hint to not use the static address, with `http`. It is better to use the wp function [`plugins_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url). Also a example:

```
    wp_register_script( self::$handle,
           plugins_url( 'js/', __FILE__ ) . 'Button.js'
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try and get back to mark as answered soon.